# How to overcome gzip/Mavericks incompatibility?

Tags: metadata, gzip, osx-mavericks, tar, textedit

So I recently changed jobs and I brought a bunch of files with me off my OS X 10.7 system.  I had way too many files than could fit on the external drive I had, so I had tried dragging select files onto the drive, which gave me eventual repeated errors, so instead I used:

`tar -zcvf whatever.tar.gz my_files`

and then dragged the gzipped tarball onto the drive and that worked just fine.  Now however, on my new Mavericks 10.9 system, I just tried to open a rich text file (that I'd created in Text Edit on 10.7) and I get the error:

'The document "_lab_notebook_2.rtf" could not be opened.'

I called Apple about this and they claimed that gzip was adding "the command line" to the metadata of the file (I assume the rich text file - though I could be wrong) and that metadata chunk is incompatible with Text Edit in Mavericks.  They said that they have a request in with the gzip developers to address this issue (by stripping out the added metadata at some point along the way).  Eventually, they say once that is updated, it will be in a new system update.

In the meantime, I'm stuck with a file that Text Edit can't open.  I can open the file in other text editors, but I really would rather use Apple's Text Edit, hence this post.  I tried opening a copy of the file with Rezilla and I can see the metadata in coded form, but nothing's jumping out at me as the offending data.  I even tried removing each resource 1 by 1 and trying to open the file after each removal, but it still would not open.

Does anyone have any hints as to how to strip out whatever it is that gzip added?  Am I even working from the correct starting point?  They said that the data was added during the zip-up of the file, and I no longer have access to the original.  Should I be working with the .tar.gz file or the .rtf file that was contained there-in?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: People would appreciate if you tried to structure your post a bit more. Try adding some paragraphs for readability.

Comment: Can I delete this question? If so, how? I got a warning about ill-received questions. Is there anything I can do to this question to eliminate the warning? Turned out the premise of the question was wrong and I'd just as soon delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are trying to open, `_lab_notebook_2.rtf` might not be the file.  (Are you sure it doesn't have a dot before the underscore, i.e. `._lab_notebook_2.rtf`?)  It may be the resource fork of the actual file, where the actual file would be named `lab_notebook_2.rtf`.

I don't know who you talked to at Apple, but gzip doesn't add anything to anything.  It is simply a lossless compression and decompression utility.  They certainly haven't contacted me about it (I am one of the gzip developers).  Please look up my contact information, e.g on [zlib.net](http://zlib.net/), and copy that email to me.  Thanks.

tar on the other hand may not be preserving all of the information that was on the original file system, or storing resource forks as `._` files, depending on what you asked it to do.  It would have been better if you had used the Finder File:Compress operation, which preserves all of that information.  (Or on the command line, the `ditto` utility with the options noted in its man page to duplicate what Finder does.)

Comment: I'll see if I can locate the follow up email after the call, look you up, and forward it to you.

Comment: Well, I've got 1 email from Apple and I recently called about 2 different issues, so I'm not sure it's the right one. But to address your comment, it is the right file. I named it with a leading underscore for sorting reasons.

Comment: Hi Mark, Just spoke with Apple again about a separate issue and I asked for the case number regarding the issue that this post was about.  I'll look up your email now and send it to you.